# .htaccess redirect code redirects to custom 404 not found instead of directing for www to non-www version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using this redirect code

```
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8mags\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://8mags.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects me to a custom 404 page that I created. Here is some additional information I got from http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
0       # Redirect www urls to non-www  
1       RewriteEngine on    
2       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8mags\.com [NC]  This condition was met
3       RewriteRule (.*) http://8mags.com/$1 [R=301,L]  This rule was met, the new url is http://8mags.com/ The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect
```

I don't understand what the last line means and how to correct the problem?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, I have other code but it is related to gzip compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick test of your URL `http://www.8mags.com/lessons/` and it gets redirected to:
`http://8mags.com/8mags/lessons/` instead of `http://8mags.com/lessons/`. Which means you've kept above rule in `/8mags/` sub-directory instead of `DocuemtnRoot`.

Move above rule to parent directory if `/8mags/` which is your `DocumentRoot`.

You can also fix it by using `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8mags\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://8mags.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Actually there are two domains hosted on he same account. The .htaccess is in root of both these, I mean common root , I willl edit the redirect code and tell if If the problem is resolved.

Comment: Nope problem is gone, test in a new browser or clear browser cache.

Comment: Hey, thank you. You were right it is resolved now. Does a browser also catch the .htaccess file?

Comment: No browser doesn't know anything about htaccess, it only caches redirects (301)